# How to only open one dropdown at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few dropdowns on my site and I can't figure out how to get them to only open one at a time. I've tried to hide them all by default first but it still seems to open all of them at once... am I missing something? Thank you!

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="click-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the js:

```
$(function () {
  $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
  $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
  $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
         $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
         $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are using the class name to reference the dropdowns. Assign an id to each dropdown instead and use these id's to reference to them. This will give you control over which dropdown you are closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Since you already have `$(function()` which is the shortcut for `document.ready` , you don't need another `document.ready`.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
  $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();

  $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) 
                            {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(400); 
    $('.click-nav .js ul').not($(this).find('ul')).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/qky7q18d/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need it to work so that it closes the dropdown again when you click which doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a tad old but I have put a script together using unique id's for each onclick, in my case I have used an IMG rather than a button.

The below code is the drop down with a image that has an onlick that when clicked is sent into the myFunction along with a unique post id from the database this must be echo'd.
myDropdown also used for the display of the dropdown by adding toggle "show" to the dropdown-content class within it.

Also the myDropdown itself is unique by myDropdownUNIQUEPOSTID.

```
<div id="dropduttonholder"><img width="20" height="20" style="cursor:pointer;"
 onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $postid['streamitem_id'] ?>);" 
class="dropbtn" src="../newimages/postdropimg.png" /></div>
<div class="dropdown" id="<?php echo $postid['streamitem_id'] ?>">
  <div id="myDropdown<?php echo $postid['streamitem_id'] ?>" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The below script that the onlclick event sends to, will first look for any instances of dropdowns open and pass that into the CloseItemsOpen function to remove the 'show' from any dropdown-content classes.

It will then dropdown the currently clicked on drop down and also allow you to click outside the element to close it.

I also added a return to dropdown-content through target.matches to stop any dropdown that is currently open from closing when clicking inside it.

```
<script>
  function closeOpenItems() {
      openMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
      openMenus.forEach(function(menus) {
        menus.classList.remove('show');
      });  
  }

/* Javascript only */
function myFunction(streamitem_id) {
    closeOpenItems();
    var acc = document.getElementById("myDropdown"+streamitem_id).classList.toggle("show");

  }

 // Closes the menu in the event of outside click 
        window.onclick = function(event) { 
         if (event.target.matches('.dropdown-content *')) {
    return;
   } 
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

                var dropdowns =  
                document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content"); 
                  
                var i; 
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) { 
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i]; 
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) { 
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show'); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is because you don't have assigned any identity parameter to any of the drop-downs and here you have only one drop-down with different sub-nav items. Or are you referring to them as separate drop-downs? I think you should assign different id's to every element and then use the `getelementbyid` jquery function. That's how I do it. I don't know if it works for you.